# Replace column based strings with multiple with pre-defined values - Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

I am bit confused with approach to implement the below logic in python. I would need expert advice in choosing a method.

I have to replace strings with predefined values in certain columns.
For e.g.

| is delimiter

Input :

```
ABCD|NewYork|800|TU
XYA|England|589|IA
```

Output :

```
QWER|NewYork|800|PL
NHQ|England|589|DQ
```

Predefined dictionary :

```
Actual Value  : ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Replace Value : QWERTYASDFGHNBVCXZOPLKMNHY
```

So, If value is ABCD, I should get QWER. If it is TU then it should replace it with PL. The values can be random.

My approach would be like below

1. Read a line and then go to column 1
2. read each character and replace one by one by using replace values
3. Go to column 4 and then read each character and replace one by one
4. go to next line and so on....

I feel this might be poor way of coding. Is there any different way than above approach? Please suggest a method.

**Column's may be different for different files. It should be dynmaic**

Comment: Your approach sounds fine, why don't you implement it and find out!

Comment: well you can slightly speed up the look up time, if you create a dictionary which maps your actual values with replace values `{"A": "Q", "B": "W", ...}`, otherwise I dont see anything else that can be made faster

Comment: Thats a good way to code IMO. Only thing will be need to checking the performance. Why dont you code that and post here for comparision?

Comment: Building on what @N.Ivanov suggested: `dict(zip('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'QWERTYASDFGHNBVCXZOPLKMNHY'))`. I'd also use the [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) to make your life a lot easier here:

```
In [1]: fnd = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
   ...: rpl = 'QWERTYASDFGHNBVCXZOPLKMNHY'
   ...: trns = str.maketrans(fnd, rpl)

In [2]: 'ABCD'.translate(trns)
Out[2]: 'QWER'

In [4]: 'UV'.translate(trns)
Out[4]: 'LK'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using a list comprehensions with `str.join`.

The trick is to convert your dictionary to a Python `dict`.

```
x = ['ABCD|NewYork|800|TU',
     'XYA|England|589|IA']

d = dict(zip('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
             'QWERTYASDFGHNBVCXZOPLKMNHY'))

res = ['|'.join([''.join(list(map(d.get, i[0])))]+i[1:]) \
       for i in map(lambda y: y.split('|'), x)]
```

Result:

```
['QWER|NewYork|800|TU',
 'NHQ|England|589|IA']
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
from string import maketrans

actual = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

replace = 'QWERTYASDFGHNBVCXZOPLKMNHY'

with open('infile.txt') as inf, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outf:
    toBeWritten = []
    for line in inf:
        items = line.strip().split('|')
        items[0] = items[0].translate(maketrans( actual, replace))
        items[3] = items[3].translate(maketrans( actual, replace))
        print items
        toBeWritten.append('|'.join(items))
    outf.writelines(toBeWritten)
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I do it for dynamic columns? Say next file has column 2 and 3 Please let me know.

Comment: Just change the indices of items (0 and 3) into new ones.

Comment: Thanks. Will try dynamic approach and post it.